# How to write a PHP script that searches a PHP file for specific information?

Tags: php, regex, scripting, phpstorm

Disclaimer: This is my first foray into PHP and scripting in general - all of my development experience is in iOS (Swift and Objective-C). I've started doing a tutorial.

We have a large `.php` file, let's call it `objects.php`, with a number of static variables.

The structure looks something like this:

```
'ObjectDictionaryTom' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Tom"
]

'ObjectDictionaryDick' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Dick"
]

'ObjectDictionaryHarry' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Harry"
]

'ObjectDictionaryAlsoTom' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Tom"
]
```

The structure isn't consistent; Sometimes, it even looks like this:

```
`Objects` => [

'ObjectDictionaryTom' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Tom"
],

'ObjectDictionaryDick' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Dick"
],

'ObjectDictionaryHarry' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Harry"
],

'ObjectDictionaryAlsoTom' => [
    A_Class::NAME => "Tom"
]

]
```

How can I read through this file and get all objects that belong to "Tom"? Maybe gather them in a CSV?

I'm happy to edit or explain further as needed!

Comment: What would the output look like?

Comment: @JNevill I just added a little more code for clarity:

The intended output would be: `ObjectDictionaryTom, ObjectDictionaryAlsoTom`.

Comment: use array_filter, https://3v4l.org/SPJNb, repeat for nested *Objects*

Comment: So that's not valid PHP, is that what is in the file?

Comment: @AbraCadaver More or less...I can't share the code exactly - is what I shared too unrealistic?

Comment: It's not PHP so it won't execute.  It may be better to execute it and do something or use reflection, but it can't if its not valid.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
'(.*?)'\s*=>\s*\[[\n\r\s]*\s*(.*?)\s*=>\s*"(.*?)"
```

[As you can see here at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1XUsrb/1)

You can see in the sidebar provided which capturing groups store which values - in particular, the ones you want are in capturing groups `1` (the first set of parentheses).

To access them, just get the values of capturing group 1 from the result.